# MYSQL or Laravel Eloquent How To Count The Detail From This Order

Tags: mysql

**[MYSQL QUERY / LARAVEL ELOQUENT QUESTION]**

Hi, I really need some help with MYSQL Query this 3 tables I have. The order table and the details it's a manually input on our system.

I'm new in MYSQL, need a help not a judge.

**PERSON TABLE** (persons)

| ID | PERSON_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jackie |
| 2 | Chan |

**ORDER TABLE** (orders)

| ID | PERSON_ID | ORDER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (Jackie) | January 01, 2022 |
| 2 | 1 (Jackie) | January 02, 2022 |
| 3 | 2 (Chan) | January 02, 2022 |
| 4 | 2 (Chan) | January 03, 2022 |
| 5 | 1 (Jackie) | January 04, 2022 |
| 6 | 1 (Jackie) | January 05, 2022 |

**ORDER DETAIL TABLE** (order_details)

| ID | ORDER_ID | DESCRIPTION | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Apple | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | Orange | 80 |
| 3 | 1 | Mango | 90 |
| 4 | 3 | Grape | 50 |
| 5 | 3 | Apple | 100 |
| 6 | 4 | Apple | 100 |
| 7 | 5 | Orange | 80 |
| 8 | 5 | Mango | 90 |

---

**QUESTION**

Here I combined the 3 tables, and this is what I got, it's showing **Order ID 2 and 6** doesn't have any order detail added (manually) on our system let's say I forgot to add the detail. So I need to show it as an error on person page.

```
SELECT
  o.id as order_id,
  p.name as person_name,
  o.date as order_date,
  COUNT(od.id) as count_order_detail,
  SUM(od.price) as subtotal
FROM persons p
JOIN orders o ON o.person_id = p.id
JOIN order_details od ON od.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

| ORDER_ID | PERSON_NAME | ORDER_DATE | COUNT_ORDER_DETAIL | SUBTOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jackie | January 01, 2022 | 3 | 270 |
| ***2*** | ***Jackie*** | **J*anuary 02, 2022*** | ***0*** | ***0*** |
| 3 | Chan | January 02, 2022 | 2 | 150 |
| 4 | Chan | January 03, 2022 | 1 | 100 |
| 5 | Jackie | January 04, 2022 | 2 | 170 |
| ***6*** | ***Jackie*** | **J*anuary 05, 2022*** | ***0*** | ***0*** |

**EXPECTED QUERY RESULT ON MYSQL TABLE**

Here is the result I expected showing the result of order with no detail.

| PERSON_NAME | ORDERS | ERROR_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jackie | 4 Orders | 2 |
| Chan | 2 Orders | - |

How can I do it ? I tried to COUNT the COUNT but it's messed up.

***Note : Sorry for the bad grammar.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I could not get the hypen into the `ERROR_ORDER` when there are no errors, but this should be pretty close otherwise:

```
SELECT name AS PERSON_NAME, 
       CONCAT(count(id), ' Orders') AS ORDERS, 
       CONCAT(count(order_id), ': ', 
           GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ISNULL(order_id), id, NULL))) AS 'ERROR_ORDER'
FROM (
    SELECT name, o.id, order_id
      FROM persons p JOIN orders o ON o.person_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN order_details od ON od.order_id = o.id
     GROUP BY name, o.id, order_id
) x
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY ORDERS DESC;
```

Which gives:

| PERSON_NAME | ORDERS | ERROR_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jackie | 4 Orders | 2: 2,6 |
| chan | 2 Orders | null |

...or by screenshot:

[image]

Example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7034d98d103861260330746768a52ec3) with all the data.

=====

But, if you *really* only want to show 2 in the last column, without the order references, then change the last part of the select to be:

```
CONCAT(SUM(IF(ISNULL(order_id), 1, null))) AS 'ERROR_ORDER'
```

Which would look like this:

| PERSON_NAME | ORDERS | ERROR_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jackie | 4 Orders | 2 |
| chan | 2 Orders | null |

...or by screenshot:

[image]

Example [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1794dc8e1a333fed88e79e8d887969e1) for this example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer really appreciate it ! but I'm really made a mess, I edited the question (no need to show `FYI Order ID`  for `error_order` it's need to show only `2` im trying to change your query from `concat(count(order_id), ' Order No Detail' .....` to `count(order_id)` its returning error_order on all row

Comment: I updated the image, the fiddle, and the query to show 2, but also with the order references that have trouble. (to help the user save time when checking?) ... however, I also added what is needed if you really only want a single value in the last column, along with the fiddle example.

Comment: Thank you very much paul.